# Not clear on what end point to use, or what App Type to select in AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, outlook-web-addins, azure-authentication, msal.js

I am writing an Add-In that will run on the following platforms
Outlook Online (OWA)
Outlook Desktop Client (Outlook 2016)
Outlook Mobile (iOS)

The Add-In will call our in house WebAPI located on-premises.

What I'm not clear on is whether or not it makes a difference what **Type** (**Web** or **Public Client**)  I select, and what redirect URI I use.

The endpoint to our WebAPI is https://ourcompany.com/ourAPI

However, I see that for Desktop and Mobile apps, the portal offers the following choices

msalfa1909ee-89f4-422b-bfea-2e6c00ef1b53://auth
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient

https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf

I thought that an endpoint was an endpoint was an endpoint; meaning, as long as it was valid and the proper information was provided (e.g. clientID, secret, etc) that a valid token would be returned when requested, regardless of the platform.

Should the start of my initialization code be written something like this?
(I was planning on using MSAL.js)

```
Office.onReady(info){
   if( info.Platform === "Office.PlatformType.OfficeOnline" ){
       endpoint = "https://ourcompany.com/ourAPI";
   }
   else if( info.Platform === "Office.PlatformType.iOS" ){
       endpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient";
   }
   else if( info.platform === "Office.PlatformType.PC" ){
       endpoint = "msalfa1909ee-89f4-422b-bfea-2e6c00ef1b53://auth"
   }
}
```

Comment: Which add-in API are you planning to use after AAD authentication?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT:  I plan to make calls to our WebAPI located on our On-Premise servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@eZG
- the endpoint is the URL of the proetected Web API that you will call (with an access token in the Authorization header). You will always call the same endpoint whatever your application.
- The Reply URI, on the other hand, is the URI where your client application (your Add-in in that case) will receive the access token from Azure AD, so that you call your Web API.

The documentation about Redirect URIs (reply URIs) is in [MSAL | Application configuration options | Redirect URIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#redirect-uri)
In the case of desktop applications,